# Typescript not working in VS 2017 after converting packages.config to project.json

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, definitelytyped, project.json

I'm trying to convert a project to use project.json instead of packages.config for NuGet packages.

To do the conversion, I used this converter... https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TaylorSouthwickMSFT.NuGetPackagetoProjectjsonConverter

The conversion seemed to work correctly. However after doing this, I cannot get my typescript files to compile. It appears it can no longer find the *.d.ts files for any of the js modules.

I've tried using nuget to re-install the packages and js and associated DefinitelyTyped packages, but it doesn't help.

I'm guessing for some reason the typescript compilation process my project is using is not compatible with the new project.json package locations.

I've tried removing and re-installing the typescript extension, but this hasn't helped.

Is there some other way I need to be compiling typescript when using project.json NuGet packages?

I obviously took a full backup of the project before converting my packages.config file, so can restore if need be, but I would really like to try getting project.json to work properly first.

Comment: AFAIK, project.json is not supported in VS2017. When you open a project.json project in VS2017, it should convert it to a new variant of csproj (which contains package references inside). No idea how does all this affect TypeScript.

Comment: I did the actual conversion with VS2015, however VS2017 seemed to recognize the project.json correctly. NuGet used this file when adding and removing packages etc. I ended up reverting though, as even after I fixed my typescript errors, the application didn't run because of other module incompatibilities.